# What type should I declare a DateTime object in a scala class constructor?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Im trying to map rows from a cassandra table to a custom class but keep getting an IllegalArgumentException for the DateTime values. I've tried every type I can think of and they all throw the same exception. Help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a scala noob btw.

```
case class ClickData(Uuid: String, Tile: String, Latestclick: Long, OriginalTimestamp: Long, Rating: Int)

----------------------------

val data = sc.cassandraTable[ClickData]("test", "user_data")

data.foreach((i: ClickData) =>

  println("CASSIE ROW: "+i)


)
```

table row example:

```
uuid: 4hgfyt24854grh3fg34u3re47ff, tile: blah-blah, latest_click_timestamp: 2016-08-05 16:17:53+0100, original_timestamp: 2016-08-05 16:17:53+0100, rating: 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find the default Java/Scala data types in Spark [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types). Depending on what your data base actually contains you may want to try:

- `java.sql.Date` for a `DateType` column
- `java.sql.Timestamp` for a `TimestampType` column

Answer (score 0):

My parameter names did not match up with the column names, copying them out properly fixed my issue. They were of type Long as well.